# Remove White Gradient on Navigation Bar and Button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, uinavigationbar

In Mainstoryboard and the Simulator you get a plain color on the Navigation Bar and Button. But if you run on a real iPhone or iPad you get this white gradient with your color. Is there a way to remove it.

[image]iPhone Image
[image]   Improved Image

Comment: The default UINavigationBar should be the same in the Simulator and iPhone.

Comment: It is most likely that the device you are testing on has iOS 6, and the simulator version is iOS 5. The NavBar has a default white gradient in iOS 6. To remove it, you just have to customize the nav bar.

Comment: I am using xcode 4.5 which must have ios6 simulator

Comment: How do I customize the navigation bar a tutorial would be nice....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

in ios5 and later you could easily customise it using  protocol. All the view controller and UI Elements now conform to this protocol. There are typically two different type of method in UIView that can access you to UIAppearance protocol either **+ (id)appearance**  or  **+ (id)appearanceWhenContainedIn:(Class )ContainerClass**.

With the first method you can customise only one navigation bar at a time. So, if you want to customise all the instances of navigation bar you would use;

**[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:myColor];**

Or if you want to set customize navigationBar based on its position and where it is placed you would normally use,

```
[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIViewController class], nil]
       setTintColor:myNavBarColor];
```

This would modify all the existing navigation controller that are inside the view controller.

But prior ios5, it is even easier to set navigation bar tint color for some specific view controller and it is just a line of code as;

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

But, if you create the navigation bar which is not a part of navigation controller but just a view controller then keep an outlet to it and customise it as above or,

```
[self.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor violetColor]];
```

In viewDidLoad;

```
UIImage *backgroundImage = [self drawImageWithColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
 [self.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:backgroundImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];


-(UIImage*)drawImageWithColor:(UIColor*)color{
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *imagePath;
    imagePath = [[paths lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"NavImage.png"];
    if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:imagePath]){
      return  [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:imagePath]];
    }
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(320, 40));
    [color setFill];
    UIRectFill(CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40));
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    [data writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];
    return image;
}
```

Comment: Now if you could post the code or send it I could look at it.

Comment: The white gradient is white on the top then when you go down you get color you choose for the tint...

Comment: I am sorry not I really dont understand what you mean. As the figure shows you have the tint on the navigation bar. But, now what the white gradient means here.

Comment: Ok you mean the tint color. So, you just want a plane color over the navigation bar.

Comment: Thats exactly what i want….

Comment: I dont suppose there are any methods to remove the tint gradient unless you use background image for it. You could be interested in -  setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics: if you want to remove the tint gradient completely.

Comment: Ok do you Know any website where I get the images…

Comment: What king of images, do you want, a plain blue color, which color ? Why dont you create a simple image yourself. Wait I could help you with this.

Comment: A plain blue would be nice….

Comment: See my edit. This code will help you create a background image with your own color. And also disable the tint.

Comment: I am sorry I was trying to make it in Photoshop but it took ma lot of time to manage. And now I find this better since now you can change the color to anything you like.

Comment: I posted the image i am getting in the simulator….

Comment: With this edit you will be able to load the image if it is already saved in the disk and then use the same image otherwise create image and then use it and save it and on the subsequent request it will use the saved image.

Comment: @insane-36 Awesome implementation, saved me so many hours +1.